# Get IDs of all Facebook groups

Tags: python, facebook

I need to get all user's groups ID or links to those groups which he belong
The code is executing but nothing is writing down to a file
Has anyone a clue or diffret way to get groups id's
I need it to make an alghortim which will be adding specific ads on every group but i cant get the id's

```
import requests

# Replace ACCESS_TOKEN with a valid access token
ACCESS_TOKEN = "TOKEN_ACCCES"

# Set the endpoint URL
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/groups"

# Set the HTTP headers
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

# Set the params for the request
params = {
    "limit": 100,  # The maximum number of groups to retrieve per request
}

# Initialize an empty list to store the group IDs
group_ids = []

# Flag to determine whether there are more groups to retrieve
more_groups = True

# Keep making requests until all groups have been retrieved
while more_groups:
    # Send the request
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

    # Check the response status code
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print("Failed to retrieve groups")
        print(response.text)
        break

    # Extract the data from the response
    data = response.json()

    # Add the group IDs to the list
    group_ids.extend([group["id"] for group in data["data"]])

    # Check if there are more groups to retrieve
    if "paging" in data and "next" in data["paging"]:
        # Update the URL and params for the next request
        url = data["paging"]["next"]
        params = {}
    else:
        # No more groups to retrieve
        more_groups = False

# Write the group IDs to a file
with open("group_ids.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(",".join(group_ids))

print("Done!")
```

Comment: You can't spam a users group anyway.

Comment: this wan't be a scam morelikely regular advert

Comment: Advert is spam. It is not allowed.